# Will Skylanders figures work with other Skylanders games?

Tags: skylanders

My son has Skylanders: Spyro Adventure and a bunch of figures. He saw two other Skylanders games and wanted them, but I don't know if the figures and Portal of Power will work with other games. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a list.  The games are listed across the top and each series of toy are listed in the rows.

Here's the current chart offered by Activision Support.
[image]

Here's an older game chart that offers more detail on the early games.

[image: Skylander Compatability chart]

This information is from [Activision Support](https://support.activision.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/Skylanders-Toy-Compatibility-FAQ/?q=skylanders&l=en_US&c=Game_Title%3AAll&fs=RelatedArticle).

Answer (score 1):

You get a new Portal of Power with each game, so that shouldn't be an issue. Older figures work with more recent games, but more recent figures will not work with older games - if the figure didn't exist when the game was released, the game will have no way of displaying them.